# What is the feasibility of a ropeway pulling airships?

Tags: buoyancy

At a steady walking speed, a horse can move approximately fifty times as much weight in a boat as it could with a cart on old-fashioned roads.
How much could one HP move if the load was free floating and naturally buoyant?

This kind of transport system is sometimes featured in fantasy novels.  A good example would be Fool's Errant by Matthew Hughes.  Could this be a practical application in the real world?

Comment: It's a matter of torque vs. breakaway friction, as demonstrated when a single person pulls a train locomotive or a 747 jet. Barring air resistance or other opposing forces,  there is no maximum load.

Comment: Note also that if the load is naturally buoyant, it will be pulling up on the horse, which will reduce the maximum frictional force the horse can apply to the ground.